# R - Parsing XML from multiple URL to Data Frame with tydiverse and xml2

Tags: r, xml, xml2

This question will be probably be tagged as duplicated, but I just cannot make it work.
For the record, I have read all the other stackoverflow questions and read documentation.

I want to extract data reviews from itunes for multiple pages( link: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=1/xml) and I want to do it in tidy and dynamic way, preferably with *XML2* and *tydiverse*.

My final goal is:

To have a data frame with all the available fields (like ID, author,etc) in a column and filled with the data.

My struggle starts from the very start. I can only run the link and get it as XML, but I cannot run a simple line of code for the extracted XML code. I am clearly missing something here.
I also have no idea how to go through the pages. I know how many pages exist, but I want to have it in a dynamic way.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("xml2")


# Data extraction ---------------------------------------------------------

df_xml <- read_xml('https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=1/xml')

teste <- xml_text(xml_find_all(df_xml, '//feed/entry/ author')) *here I try to extract the field author*
> teste
> character(0)
```

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `xml_find_all(df_xml, '//feed/entry/ author')`, the search cannot find the nodes you are looking for because they are all within an xml namespace.

```
uri <- "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=1/xml"
my_xml <- read_xml(uri)
xml_find_all(my_xml, "//feed")
#> {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

You can find out which namespaces are used in the document like this:

```
xml_ns(my_xml)
#> d1 <-> http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
#> im <-> http://itunes.apple.com/rss
```

So you can specify the namespace that you want to use in your xpath, and you will get the node you are looking for like this:

```
xml_find_all(my_xml, "//d1:feed")
#> {xml_nodeset (1)}
#> [1] <feed xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom ...
```

This is obviously a bit annoying, since you have to prefix all your tags in the xpath with `d1:`, and the structure of your document is such that you can do without namespaces, so it is best to ignore them.

I find the easiest way to do this is to use `read_html` instead of `read_xml`, since among other things, it strips out the namespaces automatically and is more forgiving of errors. However, there is a function, `xml_ns_strip` that you can call after reading `read_xml` instead if you prefer.

So, your three options for dealing with namespaces in this document are:

1. Prefix all the tag names with `d1:`
2. Use `xml_ns_strip` after `read_xml`
3. Use `read_html`

---

This code will loop through all the pages of xml and give you a character vector of all 365 reviews. You will find that although there are 100 `content` tags in each page of the xml, that's because there are two `content` tags inside each `entry` tag. One of them has the raw text of the review, and the other has the same content but in the form of a string of html. The loop therefore discards the html containing strings in favour of the raw text:

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("xml2")

base <- "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page="
reviews <- author <- review_date <- character()
max_pages <- 100

for(i in seq(max_pages))
{
  cat("Trying", paste0(base, i, "/xml"), "\n")
  my_xml       <- paste0(base, i, "/xml") %>% read_xml() %>% xml_ns_strip()
  next_reviews <- xml_find_all(my_xml, xpath = '//feed/entry/content') %>% 
                  xml_text() %>%
                  subset(seq_along(.) %% 2 == 1)  
  if(length(next_reviews) == 0){
    result <- tibble(review_date, author, reviews)
    break
  }

  reviews      <- c(reviews, next_reviews)
  next_author  <- xml_text(xml_find_all(my_xml, xpath = '//feed/entry/author/name'))
  author       <- c(author, next_author)
  next_date    <- xml_text(xml_find_all(my_xml, xpath = '//feed/entry/updated'))
  review_date  <- c(review_date, next_date)
}
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=1/xml 
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=2/xml 
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=3/xml 
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=4/xml 
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=5/xml 
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=6/xml 
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=7/xml 
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=8/xml 
#> Trying https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=9/xml
```

And now `result` will contain a `tibble` with the three fields of interest:

```
result
#> # A tibble: 367 x 3
#>    review_date          author      reviews                                           
#>    <chr>                <chr>       <chr>                                             
#>  1 2020-05-05T02:38:35~ **stace**   "Really good and useful app. Nice to be able to g~
#>  2 2020-05-05T01:51:49~ fire-hazza~ "Not for Scotland or Wales cmon man"              
#>  3 2020-05-04T23:45:59~ Adz-Coco    "Unable to register due to NHS number. My number ~
#>  4 2020-05-04T23:34:50~ Matthew ba~ "Probably spent about £5 developing this applicat~
#>  5 2020-05-04T16:40:17~ Jenny19385~ "Why it is so complicated to sign up an account? ~
#>  6 2020-05-04T14:39:54~ Sienna hea~ "Thankyou NHS for this excellent app I feel a lot~
#>  7 2020-05-04T13:09:45~ Raresole    "A great app that lets me book appointments and a~
#>  8 2020-05-04T12:28:56~ chanters934 "Unable to login. App doesn’t recognise the code ~
#>  9 2020-05-04T11:26:44~ Ad_T        "Unfortunately my surgery must not be participati~
#> 10 2020-05-04T08:25:17~ tonyproctor "It’s a good app although would be better with a ~
#> # ... with 357 more rows
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried to add the other fields to the code but I did not quite managed it. Questions:, why are we referring to html when I am dealing with XML? Clearly it works, I am just wondering why read_html instead of read_xml. Another question, The output only produces 184 sentences. There are 100 "entry" tags per page, and there are 8 pages with comments. I was looking for around 800 reviews.